# scale the background layer touch position is changed?

Tags: iphone, ios5, cocos2d-iphone

I am doing some r &d in cocos2d.I have one backgroundLayer and add one sprite in that layer.
In touches Moved i changed the sprite position to current touch position.If background layer is not scaling that means backgroundLayer scale is 1 ,the code is run perfectly (simply set the touch position to sprite position).if i scaling the backgroundLayer i have the problem sprite doesn't move touch position ..please any one help me.

Here is my code:

```
layer1=[CCLayer node];
[self addChild:layer1];
layer1.scale=2;

iconImg=[CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"Icon-72.png"];
iconImg.position=ccp(512,384);
[layer1 addChild:iconImg];
```

In Touches Moved

```
iconImg.position=tchLocation;
```

My problem is after scaling the backgroundLayer how to find the touch position according to the background layer position..any one guide me...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How do you calculate your **tchLocation**?

It should work with:

```
CGPoint *tchLocation = [layer1 convertTouchToNodeSpace:touch];
```

Where touch is your **UITouch**.